# One HTTP load balancer for instances in multiple data centers

Tags: networking, vpn, linux-networking, load-balancing

We have a multitenant product where each customer get's their own subdomain (customer1.app.com, customer2.app.com, customer3.app.com). Additionally each of the customers get their own dedicated VM. Currently all of the VMs are hosted in the same Data Center, however we expect for regulatory compliance and for other business reasons that for some future customers we will have to host in another data center (other country). Currently each VM (and by extension, each customer) gets a dedicated IP and then each subdomain is pointed to the dedicated IP address. However as we scale we find this approach not appropriate any more, so we intend to introduce HAProxy as a load balancer that will route to the appropriate VM based on the subdomain.

Since all VMs are in the same network in the same data center currently, the LB can be configured to route to the private ip of each VM, so no dedicated public IPs will be necessary.

What would be the best solution to route to VMs hosted in other DCs without having dedicated public IP addresses for each VM?

Here's a diagram illustrating the topograpy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using at least one public IP and load balancer for each datacenter. If you have separate subdomains and VMs for each client, you just need to keep track of what client/subdomain is hosted in which datacenter and point the DNS at the appropriate load balancer.

I would not try to use a single load balancer across multiple datacenters: You'll increase network latency and you'll make all clients dependent on your main datacenter working, introducing a single point of failure.